# Scope in higher order functions in Java 8 lambda syntax of Combinator Pattern

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, closures

I'm trying to understand the syntax in the `create` method of the following example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

@FunctionalInterface
interface Before<T, R> extends Function<Consumer<T>, Function<Function<T, R>, Function<T, R>>> {

    static <T, R> Before<T, R> create() {
        return before -> function -> argument -> {
            before.accept(argument);
            return function.apply(argument);
        };
    }

    static <T, R> Function<T, R> decorate(Consumer<T> before, Function<T, R> function) {
        return Before.<T, R>create().apply(before).apply(function);
    }
}

public class BeforeExample {

    void demo() {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Starting BEFORE combinator demo...");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

        Function<BigDecimal, String> addTax = this::addTax;

        Consumer<BigDecimal> before = this::before;

        Function<BigDecimal, String> addTaxDecorated = Before.decorate(before, addTax);

        BigDecimal argument = new BigDecimal("100");
        String result = addTaxDecorated.apply(argument);

        System.out.println("Done - Result is " + result);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void before(BigDecimal argument) {
        System.out.println("BEFORE: Argument is " + argument);
    }

    private String addTax(BigDecimal amount) {
        System.out.println("Adding heavy taxes to our poor citizen...");
        return "$" + amount.multiply(new BigDecimal("1.22"));
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain:

- what is going on in the `return before -> function -> argument -> {...}` block and how the variables `before`, `function` and `argument` become known without seemingly being passed into `create`'s signature, as well as
- what the multiple `->` signify.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> what is going on in the return before -> function -> argument -> {...}
>   block and how the variables before, function and argument become known
>   without seemingly being passed in

The following piece of code can help you understand the block and the usage of variables within:

```
static <T, R> Before<T, R> create() {
    return new Before<T, R>() {
        @Override
        public Function<Function<T, R>, Function<T, R>> apply(Consumer<T> before) {
            return new Function<Function<T, R>, Function<T, R>>() {
                @Override
                public Function<T, R> apply(Function<T, R> function) {
                    return new Function<T, R>() {
                        @Override
                        public R apply(T argument) {
                            before.accept(argument);
                            return function.apply(argument);
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

> what the multiple `->` signify.

The lambda representation for each of those functional interfaces combined to represent the implementation of `create` method.